# Runtime Error after taking screenshots in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following code

```
 public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        int width = GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Width;
        int height =  GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Height;
        Logger.log("width and height: " + width + "," + height, 0);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Size);
        return bmp;
    }
```

My application takes a lot of screen shots for screen scraping purposes. So this method is called once every 3 seconds roughly. It always starts fine, but after a while I get exceptions here. If I build in error tolerance (to just try again on exception) it does keep running, but my logs show lots of failed attempts.

These are the 3 exceptions:

```
Exception caught : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is incorrect
at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)
   at MoonHandler.scraping.User32Facade.PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd) in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\User32Facade.cs:line 50
   at MoonHandler.scraping.MoonFacade.getBMP(Boolean fresh) in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\MoonFacade.cs:line 37
   at MoonHandler.scraping.MoonFacade.isWarpDriveActive() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\MoonFacade.cs:line 154
   at MoonHandler.logic.MoonLogic.warping_to_belt() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\logic\MoonLogic.cs:line 113
   at MoonHandler.logic.MoonLogic.act() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\logic\MoonLogic.cs:line 47

Exception caught : System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)
   at MoonHandler.scraping.User32Facade.PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd) in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\User32Facade.cs:line 50
   at MoonHandler.scraping.MoonFacade.getBMP(Boolean fresh) in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\MoonFacade.cs:line 37
   at MoonHandler.scraping.MoonFacade.isWarpDriveActive() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\MoonFacade.cs:line 154
   at MoonHandler.logic.MoonLogic.warping_to_belt() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\logic\MoonLogic.cs:line 113
   at MoonHandler.logic.MoonLogic.act() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\logic\MoonLogic.cs:line 47

Exception caught : System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at MoonHandler.scraping.User32Facade.PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd) in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\User32Facade.cs:line 48
   at MoonHandler.scraping.MoonFacade.getBMP(Boolean fresh) in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\MoonFacade.cs:line 37
   at MoonHandler.scraping.MoonFacade.isWarpDriveActive() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\scraping\MoonFacade.cs:line 154
   at MoonHandler.logic.MoonLogic.warping_to_belt() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\logic\MoonLogic.cs:line 113
   at MoonHandler.logic.MoonLogic.act() in d:\users\npiv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MoonMiner\ConsoleApplication2\logic\MoonLogic.cs:line 47
```

I realize these are 3 different exceptions, but I feel they are linked. Since it only starts happening at runtime, is this some sort of memory leak? Can I take the screen shot another way?

Comment: Can you show us your p/invoke methods?

Comment: Are you disposing your resources nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    sleep();
    int width = GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Width;
    int height =  GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Height;
    Logger.log("width and height: " + width + "," + height, 0);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Size);

    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but System.Drawing.Graphics and System.Drawing.Bitmap implements IDisposable. And the fact it plays with GDI resources leads me to think you have a resource leak...

*(Which I never fail to find funny, considering the kind of language, but I disgress)*

Anyway, you should consider disposing the `Graphics` and `Bitmap` objects.

Something like:

```
public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    int width = GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Width;
    int height =  GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Height;
    Logger.log("width and height: " + width + "," + height, 0);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    // the following line will make sure memoryGraphics
    // will be disposed nicely.
    using(Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
       memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, GetWindowInfo(hWnd).rcWindow.Size);
    }

    return bmp;
} // And don't forget to dispose of Bitmap when not used anymore !!!
  // call: bmp.Dispose() once you don't need it anymore.
```

Sources:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, but just in case someone (like myself) stumbles into these errors trying to do C# screen capturing:

1. **"Parameter is not valid." in Bitmap ctor** occurred when I tried to pass an empty coords there (which were empty because I called GetClientRect on already closed window's hWnd).
2. **"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is incorrect"** in CopyFromScreen occurs when there's no primary desktop visible - for example, in service mode, or (in my case) when user presses "Ctrl-Alt-Del" in Windows 7/8.

Hope this helps someone. ;)

Comment: I am facing issue in case 2. When user presses Ctrl-Alt-Del `CopyFromScreen` throws exception. How to solve this?