# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid copfromscreen() function

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to capture the screen this code is working on local server but when i but this on web server System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid exception appears. this is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);
using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,0,0,bitmap.Size,CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        //// graphics.CopyFromScreen(143, 63, 100, 100, bitmap.Size);
}
```

and here is the exception:

> [ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
>      System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc() +1138213
>      System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation) +413
>      _Default.Button9_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\home\site\wwwroot\CS.aspx.cs:173
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9654230
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639'

Comment: Are you trying to make a screenshot of the client-desktop from the server side code? This will not work with the `Graphics` object, since the code is running on the server. You'll have to look up a client-side solution for creating a screenshot (probably using JavaScript or something similar).

Comment: What code have you got after CopyFromScreen?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788276/runtime-error-after-taking-screenshots-in-net

Comment: i am croping that screen shot.. but code is bit lengthy can't past here

Comment: thnks for reply by the way..but link you have posted is not the solution. i am capturing the browser basically. and after taking screen shot i 'll crop the portion i need